# Left Join the same table based on two different fields?

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have two tables...

```
SELECT * FROM posts  
post_id | user_id | timestamp | feed_id | content

SELECT * FROM users  
user_id | username | display_name
```

I have the following MySQL query to get the posts and LEFT JOIN the corresponding user information that posted it... then sort the posts by the timestamp posted.

```
SELECT posts.*, users.* FROM `posts` LEFT JOIN `users` ON posts.user_id=users.user_id ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC LIMIT 0, 15
```

Now, the `posts.feed_id` will either be NULL, which is a "general post," but it can also be another user_id, which is a post directed towards that user.

How can I add another JOIN statement to get that user information, if available --- on `posts.feed_id=users.user_id`

Something like (but not this, this does not get what I want):

```
SELECT posts.*, users.* FROM `posts` LEFT JOIN `users` ON posts.user_id=users.user_id AND posts.feed_id=users.user_id ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC LIMIT 0, 15
```

I'm sure I'd have to alias the information accordingly, but I can't seem to retrieve it at all

Comment: You have to join the `users` table twice. Once for the `user_id` and once for the `feed_id`. In that case it will work :)

Comment: good question.  sometimes we get stuck in a relatonal labyrinth with the door staring right at us.  UPVOTED :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join twice with different aliases:

```
SELECT posts.*, source.*, target.*
FROM `posts` 
LEFT JOIN `users` as source ON posts.user_id=source.user_id
LEFT JOIN `users` as target on posts.feed_id=target.user_id
ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC LIMIT 0, 15
```

You'll probably want to explicitly list the columns instead of `source.*` and `target.*` so you can give them distinct names.

Comment: I do have them listed, but shortened it for my question (so you wouldn't have to sort through all of that!) Thanks for this! :)

Comment: @jimgarrison since you are doing 2 left joins from the same table, this statement dispenses the need for SELECT DISTINCT, right?  BTW, tks for the edit on my question re finding references to views in a db.  UPVOTED :)

Comment: what if there more then 61 columns which need join with 61 different tables ?